# How to query the database for a between-value and sort by the nearest?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, between

I'm searching a value in my MySQL-Database and want to sort the results by the nearest items.

Example:

I search for a value of 150, within my Query I now do the following:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE field BETWEEN 100 AND 200`
The 100 and the 200 are calculated before by an easy addition and substraction. But now my results are messed up, because it gives me the results back like they were saved to the database.

Is it possible  to sort the results within MySQL or do I have to sort them afterwards with PHP?

Comment: add 'Order by' clause for sorting results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE field BETWEEN 100 AND 200
ORDER BY field
```

or did you want something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE field BETWEEN 100 AND 200
ORDER BY ABS(150-field)
```

?

Anyway, there are [interactive](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) online SQL tutorials which should help you jump start your SQL skills.

Comment: well, typed more characters and had to grab a link, so yeah - you were faster! :P :)

Comment: Since you typed this 34 minutes ago, and Peter 33 minutes, you were faster. This is also why I'll accept your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Tim, well actually Peter's answer was first - it seems so stats and timestamps are not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to add an order by clause like so:

```
ORDER BY ABS(150-field)
```

Comment: assuming 150 is the value you want your results to be the nearest to